# Replace a partial with javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In one of my pages I have a partial, that I would like to replace with another when the user clicks on a link:

```
<div id="chapter_list">
<%= render 'icd1' %>
</div>
```

My actual js-code simply removes the div chapter list, when an user clicks on a page:

```
$('#chapter_list').fadeOut();
```

I tried several tings to render the partial _icd2 instead of icd1, for example:

```
$('#chapter_list').text(<%= render 'icd2' %>);
```

But had no sucess! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your js file to js.erb and use the following code:

```
$('#chapter_list').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'icd2')) %>");
```

**EDIT**

To pass a param you can do this:

```
$('#chapter_list').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'icd2', :locals => { :param => #Whatver value you wish to pass#})) %>");
```

And then you can refer to it in the partial by simply calling `param` or whatever name you give it.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer so that in the future other users know!

Comment: One more thing: How can i add an param that will be transferd to the partial?